# How to change the date format in material ui and input text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

How to change the date format in material ui and input text?
Can not format textField of type date in the form 'DD/MM/YYYY'. The options for type are limited. Why not have a format field

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker has a [format prop](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/)

The [Datefield](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-field/) component has examples of using format.

```
<DateField
  label="Dash separator"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
  format="MM-DD-YYYY"
/>
<DateField
  label="Full letter month"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
  format="LL"
/>
```